# Extract Bitmap from DLL for use in PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, dll

I'm in the process of building a little utility using powershell and have spent a good deal of time teaching myself about building windows forms and controls using powershell.  In order to keep my deployment to a small footprint I have packaged all of my graphics icons (*.ico) and images (*.bmp) in a dynamically linked library (*.dll) using a third party utilty (greenfish icon editor pro, which I highly recommend).
The problem that I have now is that I can't load the assembly because the resulting *.dll is missing a manifest. I've searched all over but was unable to find any concise answer on how to access the resource without using the add-type cmdlet to load the *.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way to load icons from a dll in an answer to [this post from Kazun](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/16444c7a-ad61-44a7-8c6f-b8d619381a27/using-icons-in-powershell-scripts?forum=winserverpowershell).  Then utilizing technet I was able to find a corresponding entry point in the dll for a method to extract a bitmap.  See my kludged together script below which combines both the IconExtractor and my newly created BitmapExtractor classes.

```
$code = @"
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace System {
    public class IconExtractor  { #Credit to Kazun from https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/16444c7a-ad61-44a7-8c6f-b8d619381a27/using-icons-in-powershell-scripts?forum=winserverpowershell
        public static Icon Extract(string file, int number, bool largeIcon) {
            IntPtr large;
            IntPtr small;
            ExtractIconEx(file, number, out large, out small, 1);
            try {
                return Icon.FromHandle(largeIcon ? large : small);
            } catch {
                return null;
            }
        }
        [DllImport("Shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "ExtractIconExW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int ExtractIconEx(string sFile, int iIndex, out IntPtr piLargeVersion, out IntPtr piSmallVersion, int amountIcons);
    }

    public class BitmapExtractor { #Credit to Chad Estes (chadwestes@gmail.com)
        public static Bitmap Extract(string file, string resourceID) {
            IntPtr hModule = LoadLibraryEx(file,IntPtr.Zero,0x00000020);
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            IntPtr hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
            try {
                if (hModule != IntPtr.Zero) {
                    hBitmap = LoadBitmap(hModule, resourceID);
                    if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero) {
                        bmp = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                bmp = null;
            } finally {
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
                FreeLibrary(hModule);
            }
            return bmp;
        }
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hReservedNull, uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadBitmap(IntPtr hInstance, string lpBitmapName);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint="DeleteObject", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hBitmap);

    }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -ReferencedAssemblies System.Drawing

$myImage = [System.BitmapExtractor]::Extract("C:\SomePath\Some.dll", "LOGO")
$myIcon = [System.IconExtractor]::Extract("C:\SomePath\Some.dll", 1, $true)
```